# How to use setinterval in Puppeteer node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, async-await, instagram, puppeteer

I want to stop my script and wait till the end then return the array. It Should not move forward without return element in puppeteer node js. It does not wait for the clear interval and move forward , so that I get undefined, how to wait for the result of the array here.

I am getting result undefined. I want to get an array.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
var page;
var browser;
async function getuser_data(callback) {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1068,
        height: 611
    });
    await page.goto(
        "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher"
    );
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');
    await page.type('input[name="username"]', "yourusername");
    await page.type('input[name="password"]', "yourpassword");
    await page.click("._0mzm-.sqdOP.L3NKy");

    await page.waitFor(3000);
    var y = "https://www.instagram.com/xyz/";
    await page.goto(y);
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    var c = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await document
            .querySelector(
                "#react-root > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"
            )
            .click();
        var i = 0;
        var timer = await setInterval(async () => {
            i = i + 1;
            console.log(i);
            await document.querySelector(".isgrP").scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
            var ele = await document.querySelectorAll(".FPmhX.notranslate._0imsa ")
                .length;
            console.log("Now length is :" + ele);
            console.log("Timer :" + i);

            if (ele > 10 && i > 20) {
                console.log("Break");
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log("after break");
                var array = [];
                for (var count = 1; count < ele; count++) {
                    try {
                        var onlyuname = await document.querySelector(
                            `body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div.isgrP > ul > div > li:nth-child(${count}) > div > div.t2ksc > div.enpQJ > div.d7ByH > a`
                        ).innerText;
                        console.log(onlyuname);
                        var obj = {
                            username: onlyuname
                        };
                        console.log(obj);
                        await array.push(obj);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log("Not found");
                    }
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
                return array;   //Should Wait Till return , it should not move forward
            }
        }, 800);
    });
    console.log(c)  //IT should return me array, Instead of undefined
    callback(c)
}

getuser_data(users => {
    console.log(users)
    let treeusernamefile = JSON.stringify(users);
    fs.writeFileSync('tablebay.json', treeusernamefile);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `setInterval()` does not work as you expect. Specifically, it does not return a `Promise` that you could `await`. It synchronously creates the interval, and then the whole function that you pass to `page.evaluate()` returns.

What you need to do is to create a `Promise` yourself and tell it to `resolve` once you have the `array` ready.

```
//...

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var timer = setInterval(async () => {
            i = i + 1;
            console.log(i);
            await document.querySelector(".isgrP").scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
            var ele = await document.querySelectorAll(".FPmhX.notranslate._0imsa ")
                .length;
            console.log("Now length is :" + ele);
            console.log("Timer :" + i);

            if (ele > 10 && i > 20) {
                console.log("Break");
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log("after break");
                var array = [];
                for (var count = 1; count < ele; count++) {
                    try {
                        var onlyuname = await document.querySelector(
                            `body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div.isgrP > ul > div > li:nth-child(${count}) > div > div.t2ksc > div.enpQJ > div.d7ByH > a`
                        ).innerText;
                        console.log(onlyuname);
                        var obj = {
                            username: onlyuname
                        };
                        console.log(obj);
                        await array.push(obj);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log("Not found");
                    }
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
                resolve(array);   // <-----------------
            }
        }, 800);
})

//...
```

Note that the example above does not handle errors. If any of the functions in your `setInterval` throw, you need to catch those errors and pass them to the outer scope with `reject`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 This looks a straightforward solution than mine. Just returning a promise and resolving later. Mine was to return a promise recursively.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout`, promises and recursive functions might be of help.

```js
// a normal delay function, you can call this with await
const delay = d => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d))

const data = [];

async function timer(i = 0) {
  // Optionally set to wait 1000 ms and then continue
  await delay(1000)

  // click element, grab data etc.
  console.log(`Clicking element ${i}`);
  data.push(i);

  // check for condition fulfillment, you can basically put any limit here
  if (i >= 10) return data;

  // return another promise recursively here
  return timer(i + 1)
}

timer().then(console.log)
```

Run the code snippet to see in action. It should recursively show the console until it hit some limit.

The way it works is, it will return another promise if the condition are not fulfilled yet. You can call it infinitely and clear the timeout (aka return a data instead of another timer promise).